# Helping BigQuery parallelize more effectively

Tags: google-bigquery

I am attempting to run a large BigQuery query (pasted below) to generate a new derived table.  The source table has three array columns and I want to calculate the median of one array, the mode of another, and the value counts for the third.  The source table has 160k rows and the arrays are large.  The query can not complete in six hours.

However, if I split the query into multiple queries, the smaller queries are much faster.  The query is simple applying a transformation to each row of the source table to produce a row of the output table, so it is simple to split the query up into multiple queries, each of which processes one or more rows.

This solution can work for me (although I need to find out how to increase my simultaneous query limit beyond 100), but it seems that BigQuery should be able to do this sort of parallelization under the hood.  Is there some functionality that allows me to help BigQuery parallelize appropriately?  It seems what I'm doing is not overwhelmingly large and, with appropriate parallelization, BigQuery should be able to handle it in less than six hours.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE derived.carbontest400agg AS
SELECT
  cell,
  minx,
  maxx,
  x,
  y,
  PERCENTILE_CONT(ndvi, 0.5) OVER(PARTITION BY x, y) AS median_ndvi,
  (
    SELECT
      mode
    FROM (
      SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c DESC) AS rn,
        cz AS mode
      FROM (
        SELECT
          cz,
          COUNT(cz) AS c
        FROM
          UNNEST(cz_values) cz
        GROUP BY
          cz
      )
     )
     WHERE rn = 1
   ) AS cz_mode,
   (SELECT ARRAY(
       SELECT AS STRUCT
         lc,
         COUNT(lc) AS count
       FROM
         UNNEST(lc_values) AS lc
       GROUP BY
         lc
     ) AS lc_counts) AS lc_counts
FROM
  `abiding-center-290412.derived.carbontest400`
CROSS JOIN
  UNNEST(ndvi_values) AS ndvi
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe removing `cross join` will help:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE derived.carbontest400agg AS
SELECT
  cell,
  minx,
  maxx,
  x,
  y,
  (SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(ndvi, 0.5) OVER() FROM UNNEST(ndvi_values) AS ndvi LIMIT 1) AS median_ndvi,
  (
    SELECT
      mode
    FROM (
      SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c DESC) AS rn,
        cz AS mode
      FROM (
        SELECT
          cz,
          COUNT(cz) AS c
        FROM
          UNNEST(cz_values) cz
        GROUP BY
          cz
      )
     )
     WHERE rn = 1
   ) AS cz_mode,
   (SELECT ARRAY(
       SELECT AS STRUCT
         lc,
         COUNT(lc) AS count
       FROM
         UNNEST(lc_values) AS lc
       GROUP BY
         lc
     ) AS lc_counts) AS lc_counts
FROM
  `abiding-center-290412.derived.carbontest400`
```

Comment: Thanks!  That does help a lot.  For posterity, the line needs to be `(SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(ndvi, 0.5) OVER(PARTITION BY x, y) FROM UNNEST(ndvi_values) AS ndvi LIMIT 1) AS median_ndvi,` because percentile_cont  returns the value for every row rather than a single scalar.  That was a mistake you copied from me though ;)

I'll leave this open as I'd still like to understand why BigQuery is not effectively parallelizing the query and whether there is some way to help it do so,

Comment: Oh, sorry. Maybe you need `PERCENTILE_CONT(ndvi, 0.5) OVER()` though, since it is an array of values from a single `abiding-center-290412.derived.carbontest400` row. Edited the answer.

Comment: APPROX_QUANTILES could be a good fit too. `SELECT APPROX_QUANTILES(ndvi, 100)[OFFSET(50)] FROM UNNEST(ndvi_values) AS ndvi`

Comment: Performance boost is because BigQuery is now processing much less rows (cross join with `unnest` basically multiplies every row from `abiding-center-290412.derived.carbontest400` by number of elements in the `ndvi_values`).

Comment: "Execution details" in the old UI (hide preview features) could be useful for the assessment of the resources used during execution.

Comment: I think the `OVER(x, y)` is actually necessary, since I do want the median for each cell.  It returns a value for each row within each `x,y` bucket, but those values are all identical and all the median.  I noticed the Google docs for `PERCENTILE_CONT` all have a `LIMIT 1` clause without much explanation....

Comment: Yes, LIMIT is required :)

Comment: If `x` and `y` are inside `ndvi_values` array, then results of my query would probably be different from yours. Please double-check the output values manually.

Comment: Nope.  Sorry, I probably should have included a schema.  `x` and `y` are other columns and `ndvi_values` is just an array of `INTEGER`s.  Thanks again!